# Use of extern variable in c

Tags: c, extern

I have made two files in c i.e. `file1.c` `file2.c`. In file1.c I wrote

```
#include< stdio.h >                           
 int s=10;                                                                        
 void main()         
 {    
   printf("This is file 1");    
 }
```

In file2.c

```
include < stdio.h >                                                             
 extern int s;                                                                
 void main()    {                                                                         
    printf("%d",s);                                                                      
}
```

When I compiled file2.c in ubuntu terminal I got `undefined referenced` to s error. 
How can I resolve this error?

Comment: 1) the signature for `main()` ALWAYS returns `int`, not `void`  2) there can be only 1 function named `main()`  3)  have one of those files (the one that finally contains the `main()` function, call the (new function name) in the second file AND provide a prototype for that (new function name) in the file that contains the `main()` function.

Comment: you seem to have a misunderstanding about 'compiling' and 'linking'  The compiler will NOT complain about the `s` variable, HOWEVER, the linker will complain,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In file1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunction( void );

int s=10;
void myfunction()
{
    printf("This is file 1");
}
```

In file2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunction( void );
extern int s;

int main( void )
{
    myfunction();
    printf("%d",s);
}
```

then compile (the example uses `gcc`

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -c file1.c -o file1.o
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -c file2.c -o file2.o
```

then link using:

```
gcc -g file1.o file2.o -o myexec
```

then run it as

```
./myexec
```

Of course, if your using Visual Studio, the command line statements will be slightly different

Comment: Thanks @user3629249 for your response.  It is working fine. But I want to just know is there any way where it can work for two main function

Comment: to have more that one `main()` function means more than one executable program.  then need to be able to communicate between those separate programs.  There are several methods.  The easiest would be to run the first program, have it `fork()` and `exec..()` the second program.  (the second program gets a copy of the data defined in the first program).  There are other methods like shared memory (depreciated), `mmap()`, pipes, etc etc

Answer (score 3):

In the second case,

```
  extern int s;
```

tells the compiler that "somewhere there" exists a variable `s` which has type `int`, but it actually does not "define" the variable. So, the linker has no clue where to find the variable, it cannot find the variable and throws the error.

You need to have a definition of the variable, either in a separate translation unit (the purpose of using `extern`) or in the same translation unit (if you want).